# File robots.txt needed in Craft package?

Tags: config, installation, seo

I dont understand why we need the `robots.txt`file in the Craft CMS package. I think it is confusing. (I had a problem with Google indexing one of my BETA hidden website because of that.)

Reason : When I initiate my domain name on the hosting it creates automatically a **public folder** inside the **virtual host main folder**.

So for example my hosting server make the domain name point to `/lamp0/web/vhosts/public/`. So I just have to upload `craft` and `public` folders below in `/lamp0/web/vhosts/`.
Then I just have to rename `public` in `htdocs` and no need of `robots.txt` file because `craft` folder is below domain name root.

[image]

```
# Don't allow web crawlers to index Craft
User-agent: *
Disallow: /craft/
```

=========================
**UPDATE**
OK I see now in the Craft install documentation (see below). I missed it sorry.
Perhaps would it be good to insert a `README.txt` file in the package next to robots.txt file to explain that again :)
[image]

Comment: Most probably don't. However, not all hosting providers allow users to edit files above the webroot (or some users just prefer both `/craft` and public files in the same directory), in which case providing a default robots.txt file preconfigured to disallow `/craft/` folder indexing is probably a good security measure (especially for those that don't know such a thing even exists). But feel free to add it as a suggestion to [http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's there to protect those who can't have craft/ below web root. In your case it can't be found by search engines, so you *can* delete it.

Answer (score 4):

The specific directive to disallow the `/craft/` directory isn't necessary if your craft folder is below the webroot.

However, it's good practice to have a `robots.txt` for each site, so I don't recommend deleting it altogether. You can change the directives to fit whatever robots criteria you need for your site. (For example, if you launch a beta site, you'd want to Disallow the whole thing to avoid duplicate content penalties.)